# unforunately android data has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is the code am using to save in android database...but it shows an error "unforunately android data has stopped"

```
    package com.andro;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class AndroidDataActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button submitbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            submitbutton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
            try
            {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test");
                EditText i1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String number=i1.getText().toString();
                EditText i2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String name=i2.getText().toString();
                PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into test values(?,?)");
                pst.setString(1,number);
                pst.setString(2,name);
                pst.executeUpdate();


                }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
             }

             }

}
```

so why does this error occur...can i do it with 1.5 emulator...because i tried with 2.0....will 1.5 solve this problem

Comment: Can you please post the logcat error traces?

Comment: @Adel Boutros do u mean the console output??...i cant get u friend..

Comment: No. I mean the **logcat** output where it shows you all the errors

Comment: In eclipse: Window > Show view > Other, Android > Logcat

Comment: I don't wanna be rude but you should really take an android tutorial first. you have a lot o errors, you are casting your activity to onclicklistener, you should use sqlite for database... here is a good starting point http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html for sqlite and Android too

Answer (score 0):

You are catching and silently ignoring all exception. You should at least log them:

```
log.e("AndroidDataActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
```

Now, find the exception and update your question.